# Regex operation not working with last slash

Tags: java, regex, url, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

```
/abc/cde/v1a1/xxxx
/abc/cde/v1a1/xxxx/
/abc/cde/v1a1/xxxx/aqwe
/abc/cde/v1a1/xxxx/aqwe/
```

I need to fetch some string "xxxx" with above combinations. I have something like
`/.*/cde/v.*/(.*?(?P<fetch>.*?))/.*` but this doesn't work for
`/abc/cde/v1a1/xxxx`

Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing that is missing is a '?' in the regex to make the last slash optional. You would have something like this:
`/.*/cde/v.*/(.*?(?P<fetch>.*?))/?.*`